# How do you register/unregister an EXE as a COM object from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, com, regasm

***EDIT 5/11/2013***: This question originally asked how to programmatically register a COM object using code from .NET without having to use REGASM. Yahia's answer covers both how to register a DLL programmatically and an EXE.

***ORIGINAL QUESTION***: At the moment, we have a batch script that we call from our UI to register/unregister our software in COM when setting the default version (using regasm and adding registry entries). We no longer wish to use a batch script as we are running into a problem where if the script fails, the program is not aware of the failure. There are several ways I can address the issue, but I don't like the notion of calling batch scripts from code if I don't have to, so I'd like to switch to registering our software with COM using managed code.

Assuming it's possible, how do you register/unregister COM objects from C#? Googling only turns up ways to do this from installer packages, or tells me to use regasm, but I can't find any information on how to do this programmatically or if it's even possible.

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this.

***EDIT 5/10/2013***: It looks like registering an EXE as a COM object is not the same as registering a DLL. Is there a programmatic way in .NET (PInvoke is fine) to register an EXE as a COM object (in the 32 bit registry)? This is currently how we're doing it in the script, the app and REGCMD vars are just shorthand:

```
    set app=%PathToTheExecutable%
    set REGCMD=%PathTo32BitRegExe%
    "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm" /tlb /codebase %app%
    %REGCMD% ADD HKCR\CLSID\{app-guid}\LocalServer32 /ve /t REG_SZ /d %app% /f
    %REGCMD% DELETE HKCR\CLSID\{app-guid}\InprocServer32 /f
```

Basically we run regasm on the executable, then add our exe as a LocalServer32 and remove the entry which associates us as an InprocServer. Is it possible to do this programmatically without having to call regasm from code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in C# - but only by using some pinvoke, specifically LoadLibrary / GetProcAddress / FreeLibrary.

Basically you need to load the DLL, call the register/unregister functions inside that DLL and then unload it.

For a complete walkthrough including working C# source code see [here](http://www.zorched.net/2009/01/01/register-and-unregister-com-dll-from-net-code/). Reference see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as per comment.

**UPDATE after the OP updated the question:**

The above method only works for DLLs.

With Assemblies (esp. EXE COM-server implemented in .NET) the easiest and most robust option is actually to use `regasm`.

IF you really need to do this programmatically you should take a look at these MSDN-links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registerassembly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.registrationservices.registertypeforcomclients%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Basically you need to load your EXE via `Assembly.Load` and then call `RegisterTypeForComClients` on the relevant `Type`s.

Another option is to do this dynamically (at runtime) - perhaps [this](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/772961-com-servers-implemented-net) is of some use to you...

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to answer my question saying that I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693449(v=vs.85).aspx, which explains what I need to do.

Comment: @AlexanderMiles just added that MSDN link as reference.

Comment: Quick question, does it matter if what I'm registering is an EXE instead of a DLL?

Comment: @AlexanderMiles yes, because an EXE does not export any functions and can't be loaded with LoadLibrary... an EXE usually has some commandline parameter like "register" which can be used for this...

Comment: Alright. I'm going to update my question for this then, I didn't think there would be a difference between the assembly types.

Comment: Great answer, @Yahia! This is why I love this site.

Comment: One final update, if you need to register a type library, documentation here(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9142y43c(v=vs.100).aspx) states that you must call regasm as .NET will not generate a type library for you.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same problem and every solution i find is regarding the registration of dll files and not exes. Could you please share what you finalized to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked on that project, I think we just left it to call `regasm` since we were trying to register an EXE. That said, @Yahia's last few lines do offer potential solutions, but I can't speak to them myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regsvr32", "msxml6.dll /s");
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(proc.ExitCode);

proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("regasm", name+" /silent");
proc.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(proc.ExitCode);
```

Now you have the exit code, the result of the registering.  Testing on msxml6 had an exit code of '0' for success, and when I poorly named it exit code of '3'.

Comment: This is essentially what we are already doing, I'd like to find a way to do this without creating an external process. Part of the problem is that even if I check the exit code, I don't know what the other exit codes mean, and I need to inform the user accordingly as to why registering COM failed, not just that it did not succeed.

Comment: A batch script is very different.  This way you do get the exit codes of each register.  But see @Zoomln's link for pinvoke.